# Cloning a site in WPEngine

Tags: wordpress, error

I'm running CiviCRM on WPEngine. It works real fast and seems to be working well otherwise. No error logs occur on production side. The staging environment does not work, I get a 500 error when I try to access Civi there.

I also tried to clone the install and create a testing area but that also gives the same issue.

I am getting this error.

Does anyone know how this would be resolved? Thanks!

[Thu Jul 27 14:02:29.745288 2017] [:error] [pid 26200] [client 88.87.189.26:25979] PHP Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'CRM/Core/ClassLoader.php' (include_path='.:/nas/content/live/lpiacrm/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/:/nas/content/live/lpiacrm/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm//packages:.:/usr/share/php') in /nas/content/live/lpiacrmtest/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/civicrm.settings.php on line 467, referer: https://lpiacrmtest.wpengine.com/wp-admin/

Comment: The above error code was on the cloned install. Below is an error for the staging site [Wed Jul 26 03:14:25.074706 2017] [:error] [pid 5364] [client 184.97.200.126:45698] [wpengine] failed to read config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error message has a path with the word "live" in it (`/nas/content/live/etc`) which suggests that the `civicrm_root` value hasn't been changed on the test site.

`civicrm.settings.php` is the equivalent of `wp-config.php` - you need a separate version of this file for your live and test sites.  Please review your test site's `civicrm.settings.php` - not just to fix the `civicrm_root` but also the database settings, base URL, etc.

Comment: As an aside - I'm glad to hear that CiviCRM is running OK on WPEngine!  Last time I tried they had a lot of the limitations that I associate with PaaS that made running Civi difficult.